# Slim Framework and getParsedBody for delete request

Tags: php, slim, http-delete, slim-3

I'm trying to get parameters passed in the body (from a form) as DELETE request to the API as

```
$allVars = $request->getParsedBody();
```

but for some reason it will be empty when works fine for POST and PUT requests.

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) a `DELETE` request body should be ignored by servers since there are no "defined semantics":

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

It is a little bit unusual to utilize a request body for DELETE http requests. Many HTTP client libraries don't support it, so it forces a developer to construct requests from low level. Another thing, I guess that some popular web servers if use them as proxy, cut body for DELETE requests as they do for GET by default, so it requires additional configuration for them.

I would put them in the URL path or in the URL query parameters, for example:

`DELETE /resource/1234`

[Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request)